# Алгоритм обратного распространения ошибки

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте,  возникла проблема, необходимо написать программу, реализующую нейронную сеть (многослойную) с помощью алгоритма обратного распространения ошибки. Нуждаюсь в примерных  исходниках на C#.

Comment: Примерных исходниках? Зачем? Есть же подробные описания метода. Он несложен, особенно если не вводить амортизирующий коэффициент.

Comment: cy6erGn0m, удивляюсь тебе! есть хоть одна область компьютерных знаний, в которой ты не разбираешься?=)
Извиняюсь за офф:)

Answer (score 1):

Хорошая библиотека на C#, включающая работу с нейронными сетями,  - [AForge.Neuro](http://code.google.com/p/aforge/). Вдобавок:

- [C# Neural network library](http://franck.fleurey.free.fr/NeuralNetwork/)
- [NeuronDotNet - Neural Networks in C#](http://sourceforge.net/projects/neurondotnet/)

Кроме того, Википедия содержит прямую ссылку на проект, реализующий обратное распространение ошибки на C#.

Answer (score 0):

Исходный код на C++: [ai.obrazec.ru/source.htm](http://ai.obrazec.ru/source.htm), хотя проще было бы самому разобраться и написать, чем вникать в чужие коды.

Comment: @ХэшКод После ваших исправлений получается вовсе не то, что хотел написать автор.

Comment: @alvin Вы всегда можете исправить наши правки так, как Вы считаете нужным: наша правка не является обязательной и окончательной версией.